# How do i figure out which Hadoop version will work on my Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit?

Tags: 14.10, synaptic, hadoop

I usually use synaptic but when i type in Hadoop nothing shows up. Show i guess this means i am going to have to build it. I have found what seems to be a hopefully doable set of instructions to accomplish this. However, I do not know which one is made for Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit. Here is the site i am on:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Then i get directed to this mirror site but i do not know which installation to pick:

http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/hadoop/common/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Docker](https://www.docker.io/), which is a simple way to manage Linux containers.

The advantage is that your local install won't get messy when experimenting with Hadoop, and you can just roll-back a snapshot of a container if you messed up something. Also in the [Docker Hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/) there are a lot of containers that are per-installed with Hadoop, for example;

[Ubuntu install with Hadoop and basic config](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sequenceiq/hadoop-ubuntu/)

This way you don't have to install anything by yourself, and just start the big data fun ;)

Comment: The link you put up says it works for Ubuntu 14.04. Do you think it will work on my Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit ?

Comment: Yes, Docker can run Linux distributions and versions independent from the Host OS, meaning that you can even run a Docker container based on, for example, Fedora on your Ubuntu 14.10 host. If you're totally new to Docker, I suggest you to have a look at this introduction; https://sysadmincasts.com/episodes/31-introduction-to-docker

Comment: Ok it seems to have worked :) . Can i use this like i would a typical hadoop installation ? Like if i follow a hadoop tutorial would i have to start hadoop up differently or do anything different?

Comment: No, its the same. Just be sure to run your commands/edit config in your container, and not on the host.

Comment: I don't understand. How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry i don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer...

Comment: Oh ok i understand now. Thank you very very much you saved my life bc it probably would have taken me forever to do this

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. Np, if this has solved your problem, mark the question as solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19941/discussion-between-bluerubez-and-remyseroos).